# Non-standard five-point formula for second derivative used in Tracker

Tags: calculus, derivatives, numerical-methods, approximation

[Tracker](https://physlets.org/tracker/) is an open-source program used to analyze object trajectories from video. The typical data sets Tracker produces are time series of object positions at various times, i.e., data pairs `(t_i,x_i)` for $i=1$ to $N$. The time samples are assumed to have uniform time step $t_{i}-t_{i-1}=\Delta t$. Tracker then uses this data to generates estimates for the first and second derivatives, corresponding to the velocity $v=dx/dt$ and acceleration $a=d^2x/dt^2$ respectively. By default, it does this using the following finite difference schemes:

$$v_i = \frac{x_{i+1}-x_{i-1}}{\Delta t},\qquad  a_i = \frac{1}{7(\Delta t)^2}(2x_{i+2} - x_{i+1} - 2x_i - x_{i-1} + 2x_{i-2}) $$

The first is a standard two-point formula which requires no comment. However, the standard 5-point formula for the second derivative is

$$f''(x)\approx \frac{-f(x+2h)+16 f(x+h)-30 f(x)+16f(x-h)-f(x-2h)}{12h^2} \tag{1}$$
which has error of order $O(h^4)$. (Note that this formula is exact for quartic polynomials but not quintic.) The formula used by Tracker, by contrast, would correspond to $$f''(x)\approx \frac{2f(x+2h)- f(x+h)-2 f(x)-f(x-h)+2f(x-2h)}{12h^2}. \tag{2}$$ Both sides do match in the limit $h\to 0$, but the error is instead $O(h^2)$. So Tracker uses a scheme which, on the face of it, is not as precise.

Tracker's documentation doesn't address this point in detail, but does state the following: "Note: there are many other finite difference algorithms. Tracker's algorithms define the velocity for a step to
be the average velocity over a 2-step interval, and the acceleration to be the second derivative of a parabolic fit over a 4-step interval, with the step at the center. Tracker's acceleration algorithm is less sensitive to position uncertainties than others." The last sentence is especially notable. So my question as a whole is: What's the precise motivation behind Tracker's use of approximation (2), and in what sense (if any) is it "less sensitive to position uncertainties?"

Comment: Accurateness is in the forefront only if the sampling is very tight. Otherwise, in particular if there is incertitude in data acquisition, one can understand that the Tracker's formula with its "smooth" list of coefficients $1,-1,-2,-1, 2$ can be preferable to the list of coefficients $-1,16,-30,16,-1$ of the other formula (with a big peak at its center) hugely amplifying acquisition errors that can occur at the point of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try and fit a parabola
$$
x_i=c_0+c_1t_i+c_2t_i^2+\varepsilon_i
$$
and WLOG assume $\Delta t=1$ and $t_0=0$ for easier calculation.  Using ordinary least square regression (i.e., minimizing $\sum\varepsilon_i^2$), we need to solve the system
\begin{align*}
5 c_0 + 10 c_2 &=\sum_{i=-2}^2 x_i\\
10 c_1 &=\sum_{i=-2}^2 ix_i\\
10 c_0 + 34 c_2 &=\sum_{i=-2}^2 i^2x_i
\end{align*}
i.e.,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
c_0\\c_1\\c_2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\dots\\
\frac1{10}\sum_{i=-2}^2 ix_i\\
\frac1{14}\sum_{i=-2}^2 (i^2-2)x_i
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and the acceleration being $2c_2$ by the usual 'suvat' equations.  This gives the formula for $a$ as the Tracker doc claims.

Curiously, note that the velocity estimate $c_1$ is different here.  If we kept the two-point estimate of velocity in our fit, it would deliver a different estimate for acceleration.

---

**Edit**: After thinking more about it, "less sensitive to position uncertainties" could also mean the individual coefficients are smallest possible: $\lVert\alpha\rVert=\max_i\lvert\alpha_i\rvert$ is smallest over all $a=\sum_i \alpha_i x_i$ while still accurate for the case of uniform acceleration (so the error of a single reading contributes as little as possible).  Clearly we only need to consider $\alpha_i=\alpha_{-i}$ (otherwise we take the average of $\alpha$ and its reverse yielding something with no larger $\lVert\cdot\rVert$).  So $\alpha$ is an affine combination of $(\frac14,0,-\frac12,0,\frac14)$ and $(0,1,-2,1,0)$
\begin{align*}
\alpha&=(\frac14,0,-\frac12,0,\frac14)\lambda + (0,1,-2,1,0)(1-\lambda)\\
&=(\frac14\lambda,1-\lambda,\frac32\lambda-2,1-\lambda,\frac14\lambda)
\end{align*}
and so we must be either $\pm\frac14\lambda=1-\lambda$, $\pm\frac14\lambda=\frac32\lambda-2$ or $\pm(1-\lambda)=\frac32\lambda-2$ and it is easy to check these cases.

Comment: This explanation squares with the paragraph quoted: "The acceleration [is taken] to be the second derivative of a parabolic fit over a 4-step interval, with the step at the center." By contrast, the velocity is obtained by considering the first derivative of a linear fit over a 2-step interval, and thus the results are different.

Comment: @Semiclassical I've edited the answer to add some further thoughts.